# Nowhere-vanishing form $\omega$ on $S^1.$

Tags: differential-geometry

This is an example(19.8 and 17.15) from Intro to manifolds by Tu.

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle defined by $x^2+y^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The 1-form $dx$ restricts from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a $1-form$ on $S^1.$ At each point $p\in S^1$, the domain of $(dx\mid_{S^1})_p$ is $T_p(S^1)$ instead of $T_p(\mathbb{R}^2)$: $(dx\mid_{S_1})_p:T_p(S^1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. At $p=(1, 0)$, a basis for the tangent space $T_p(S^1)$ is $\partial/\partial y$. Since $(dx)_p(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=0,$ we see that although $dx$ is nowhere-vanishing $1-$form on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it vanishes at $(1, 0)$, when restricted on $S^1.$ Define a $1-form$ $\omega$ on $S^1$ by $\omega=\frac{dy}{x}$ on $U_x$ and $\omega=-\frac{dx}{y}$ on $U_y$ where $U_x=\{(x,y)\in S^1\mid x\neq 0\}$ and $U_y=\{(x,y)\in S^1\mid y\neq 0\}$.

I understand $\omega$ is $C^\infty$ and nowhere-vanishing. I want to understand why $\omega$ on $S^1$ is the form $-ydx+xdy$ of Example below:

Example 17.15 (A 1-form on the circle). The velocity vector field of the unit circle $c(t)=(x,y)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $c'(t)=(-\sin t, \cos t)=(-y, x)$. Thus $X=-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is a $C^\infty$ vector field on the unit circle $S^1$. What this notation means is that if $x,y$ are the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $i:S^1\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is the inclusion map, then at a point $p=(x,y)\in S^1$, one has $i_\ast X_p=-y\partial/\partial x\mid_p+x\partial/\partial y\mid_p$, where $\partial/\partial x\mid_p$ and $\partial/\partial y\mid_p$ are tangent vectors at $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then if $\omega=-ydx+xdy$ on $S^1$, then $\omega(X)\equiv 1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $S^1$, the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$ implies that $x dx+y dy=0$, where here $dx$ and $dy$ denote the usual 1-forms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ restricted to $S^1$. So for example, on $U_x$ we can write $dx = -\frac{y}{x}dy$, and $\omega$ becomes
$$
\omega = -ydx+xdy = \frac{y^2}{x}dy+xdy = \frac{x^2+y^2}{x}dy = \frac{dy}{x}.
$$
Similarly, $\omega$ is $-\frac{dx}{y}$ on $U_y$.